# Atom error: Request for package information failed: Application error

Tags: terminal, atom-editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4r1x.png) console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFPwM.png)
atom

I want to download a package for ATOM

Comment: The package repositories were disabled in May.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968270/1329116