# Atom certificate has expired

Tags: terminal, console, certificate, atom-editor

I am trying to install `platformio-ide-terminal` into Atom 1.63.1. I got the error `certificate has expired`. I tried alternative Terminus and got the same error. Any package install attempts end with the same error. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow cannot answer customer support questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745). Please consider contacting customer support for the company in question with your issues.

Answer (score 18):

As others have pointed out, GitHub has been ”[sunsetting Atom](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/)”.  However, there are other ways to install packages in your existing Atom installation.

**Example**

```bash
# Clone the repository
git clone https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal ~/.atom/packages/platformio-ide-terminal

# Change directory to the cloned package
cd ~/.atom/packages/platformio-ide-terminal

# Install dependencies
apm install
```

If you don't use git, you can simply download the package as zip-file and extract it to the same directory as used in the example above.

Note that some packages might require an additional build step. Take a look at the `scripts` section of `package.json` if it includes one or more build commands.

**Atom Forks**

There are currently two major forks of Atom, [Pulsar](https://pulsar-edit.github.io/) and [Atom Community](https://github.com/atom-community/atom), in different development stages. The former already supports installing packages within the and provides a full replacement for `apm`.

Answer (score 7):

Atom seems dead  
It seems we have to migrate to "some alternative"…

https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/

> When we introduced Atom in 2011, we set out to give developers a text editor that was deeply customizable but also easy to use—one that made it possible for more people to build software. While that goal of growing the software creator community remains, we’ve decided to retire Atom in order to further our commitment to bringing fast and reliable software development to the cloud via Microsoft Visual Studio Code and GitHub Codespaces.

> **On June 8, 2022, we announced that we will sunset Atom and archive all projects under the organization on December 15, 2022**.

> If I’m using Atom, what changes can I expect after the sunset?
>
> - Pre-built Atom binaries can continue to downloaded from the atom repository releases
> - **Atom package management will stop working**
> - No more security updates
> - Teletype will no longer work
> - Deprecated redirects that supported downloading Electron symbols and headers will no longer work