# what is mean by "certificate has expired" in Atom

Tags: editor, atom-editor

When trying to install packages to Atom it shows this message saying that Certificate has expired and it don't show the packages as well.

I tried to install some packages to Atom after installing. Then this message popup.

Comment: https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/

Comment: Workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837424/atom-certificate-has-expired/74968270#74968270

Answer (score 0):

Since [Atom has been archived](https://github.com/atom/atom), the certificates to sign its packages have expired and it is recommended to move on to another code editor.

You could use [Pulsar](https://pulsar-edit.dev/), a fork of Atom, which will give you a similar experience without a workaround.