# Not able to install package in atom ide

Tags: package, ide, atom-editor

I want to download some packages in atom ide, I am not able to do so.
I am getting following errors...

[atom feature error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlg3N.png)

Fetching featured packages failed.Hide output…
C:\Users\prits\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.63.1\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60
packages = body.filter(function(pack) {
^

TypeError: body.filter is not a function

```
at C:\Users\prits\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.63.1\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60:27
at Request._callback (C:\Users\prits\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.63.1\resources\app\apm\lib\request.js:57:22)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\prits\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.63.1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\prits\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.63.1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)

at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)

at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\prits\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.63.1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)

at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
```

I was trying to download so packages in atom ide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837424/atom-certificate-has-expired/74968270#74968270