# Extension installation problem in Atom IDE

Tags: python, ide, atom-editor

When I try to install Atom extension in IDE, it gives an error. I leave the error photo below.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1epl.png)

i type : atom-python-run. in install packages

I was trying to install the Python extension when I encountered this error.

Comment: also, post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968270/1329116