# Atom Searching for “gpp” failed.Hide output… certificate has expired

Tags: atom-editor, installation-package

I'm trying to configure Atom for C++ and use this video https://youtu.be/9aneqcQD1Gs?t=29. But I stop in 29 sec. and can't install anything. The error message says:

> Searching for “gpp” failed.Hide output…
> certificate has expired

What is shown in the first picture.
[image: Install packages screenshot]

However the message below says:

```
Fetching featured packages failed.Hide output… 
C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60
      packages = body.filter(function(pack) {
TypeError: body.filter is not a function

at C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60:27
at Request._callback (C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\request.js:57:22)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)

at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)

at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)

at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
```

So here is the screenshot of my error.

[image: Featured packages screenshot]

I'm new to Atom, used to code with CLion and need to set my environment correctly.

I have set the MinGW and JDK 19 and have set environment variables correctly. Eclipse, Visual Studio Code and Netbeans work correctly.
[image: Environment Path variable for the system]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Well, I probably know the answer. Please tell me if I'm right. Atom has been archived.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968270/1329116