# Atom Editor - How do you install packages without using apm package installer?

Tags: github, atom-editor

I want to install a package, [bracket-colorizer](https://github.com/vn-ki/bracket-colorizer), but it doesn't show up in my package installer inside Atom by default. In [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atom/comments/zdow19/anyone_know_work_around_to_apm_going_offline/), someone replies,

> APM will stop working, but Atom packages are basically just tags on a
> github repo, so if you clone the package into ~/.atom/packages and
> checkout to a specific tag, everything should still work.

I don't know what checkout to a specific tag means here. I git cloned a package into %localappdata%\atom\packages, and went to File>Settings>Packages, but did not see it there. How do I install a package after cloning it to atom\packages? I'm using Windows 7 in case that matters.

I tried using apm but I get an error, I thought this was maybe because apm wasn't working anymore since Atom was sunset/deprecated but I saw someone else say it worked for him just a few days ago. Here is the errors I get when trying "apm" or "apm -v", or trying to install a package with apm.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/git.node'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.59.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\gi
t-utils\src\git.js
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.59.0\resources\app\apm\lib\install.js
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.59.0\resources\app\apm\lib\develop.js
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.59.0\resources\app\apm\lib\apm-cli.js
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.59.0\resources\app\apm\lib\cli.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793
:17)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.59.0\resource
s\app\apm\node_modules\←[4mgit-utils←[24m\src\git.js:3:22)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10
)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.59.0\\resources\\app\\ap
m\\node_modules\\git-utils\\src\\git.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.59.0\\resources\\app\\ap
m\\lib\\install.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.59.0\\resources\\app\\ap
m\\lib\\develop.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.59.0\\resources\\app\\ap
m\\lib\\apm-cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.59.0\\resources\\app\\ap
m\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

Are there any ways still to install Atom packages other than apm?

Comment: As you said Atom has been sunset. It seems to be the good moment to switch to its cousin Visual Studio Code and not spend too much time on something already dead. And in Vscode, this feature is bundled in that editor 

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837424/atom-certificate-has-expired/74968270#74968270

Answer (score 3):

That information for installing packages with `apm` is incomplete, but also there is an easier way to do this anyway:

- Install a recent version of [Pulsar-Edit](https://pulsar-edit.dev/download.html)
- Install the package as per normal either in the editor's GUI or with `ppm`.
- (Optional) Update the package to a newer version hosted in Github by cloning the code into the installed package directory in `$HOME/.pulsar/packages` (or elsewhere depending on OS platform).