# Searching for “autoclose-html-plus” failed.Hide output… certificate has expired

Tags: atom-editor

how to solve this problem

I want to install packages and It says certificate has expired

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837424/atom-certificate-has-expired/74968270#74968270