# Atom Packages install

Tags: package, atom-editor, emmet

I am trying to install atom-live-server into Atom 1.60.0. I got the error certificate has expired. I tried alternative Terminus and got the same error. Any package install attempts end with the same error. Please help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968270/1329116

Comment: Or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77338385/about-atom-text-editor/77526491#77526491 - TL;DR; try to use Pulsar, is the fork that still have a working package manager