# can't find atom coding app script package

Tags: javascript, cmd, atom-editor, install.packages

When I searched for a script package in atom, I found nothing:

[image: this screenshot]

And when I use `cmd` code `apm install script` it says this:

```
apm install script
Installing script to C:\Users\madya\.atom\packages C:\Users\madya\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\install.js:256
          if (body.releases.latest) {
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
    at C:\Users\madya\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\install.js:256:29
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\madya\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\request.js:57:22)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\madya\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\madya\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\madya\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
```

Comment: Atom was discontinued last year. Try searching for the Atom fork called Pulsar instead.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968270/1329116