Error trying to search for packages in atom [Fetching featured packages failed.]
Installed atom yesterday, did not mess with nothing, did not remove or edit nothing. It keeps giving me this error every time i try to search for packages
Fetching featured packages failed.Hide output…
C:\Users\yoxd1\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60
packages = body.filter(function(pack) {
^
TypeError: body.filter is not a function
at C:\Users\yoxd1\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60:27
at Request._callback (C:\Users\yoxd1\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\request.js:57:22)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\yoxd1\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
at Request. (C:\Users\yoxd1\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\yoxd1\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)

You need to update to pulsar-edit.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968270/1329116

Atom was archived, all efforts went to Visual Studio Code (I think), so it will not receive any more updates or support, you can still use it, but you will not be able to install packages, I tried and I could not.
Now I use Pulsar editor the successor of Atom, I have had no major problems and the functionality has been maintained, it is still stable and nice to use.
From the Atom page: Atom and all repositories under Atom will be archived on December 15, 2022. Learn more in our official statement.
I hope you find it useful.

Thank you for pointing out Pulsar! I didn't know such a successor of Atom exists
